# How can I find a specific status within a date range

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to find a specific `legalStatus` for a specific date range from the following table layout.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.LegalStatus (
LegalStatusID int IDENTITY,
CaseID int NOT NULL,
LegalStatusTypeID int NOT NULL,
LegalStatusDate smalldatetime NOT NULL
```

Example: I may have three status records.

```
LegalStatusID = 1,
CaseID =17,
LegalStatusTypeID = 52,
LegalStatusDate = 4/1/12

LegalStatusID = 2,
CaseID =17,
LegalStatusTypeID = 62,
LegalStatusDate = 10/1/12

LegalStatusID = 3,
CaseID =17,
LegalStatusTypeID = 72,
LegalStatusDate = 10/1/13
```

I am trying to report on all cases that have `LegalStatusTypeID` = 62 between 1/1/13 and 7/1/13.
This would be easy if there was an end date.
Help!
Andy

Comment: What do you mean by: "This would be easy if there was an end date"?  Is this something you haven't told us that complicates the question?

Comment: Hi,  Yes there is only one date.  That date may be superseded by another date.  In my example data, each `LegalStatusDate` is in effect  until another date is added.  

Each time another record is added, that record is the active legal status. So I can figure out how to determine if a legal status is active for a date range.  

In my test data the `LegalStatus` with the date of 10/1/12 would be active between 1/1/13 and 7/1/13.  

There is no end date, The next date acts as both the start date of the new record and the end date of the previous record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, if I understand your comment, for a given `CaseID`, you can have multiple records, each with with a `LegalStatusTypeID` unique to that case, each with a date, and the applicability for each `LegalStatusTypeID` is between that record's `LegalStatusDate` and *the next record entered for that case*'s `LegalStatusDate`:

```
SELECT qrySub.CaseID, qrySub.LegalStatusDate, LegalStatus.LegalStatusDate AS 
    NextLegalStatusDate
FROM (
    SELECT LegalStatus_2.LegalStatusID, LegalStatus_2.CaseID, LegalStatus_2.
        LegalStatusTypeID, LegalStatus_2.LegalStatusDate, MIN(qryNext.
            LegalStatusID) AS NextLegalStatusID
    FROM LegalStatus AS LegalStatus_2
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT LegalStatusID, CaseID, LegalStatusTypeID, LegalStatusDate
        FROM LegalStatus AS LegalStatus_1
        ) AS qryNext
        ON LegalStatus_2.CaseID = qryNext.CaseID AND LegalStatus_2.LegalStatusID 
            < qryNext.LegalStatusID
    GROUP BY LegalStatus_2.LegalStatusID, LegalStatus_2.CaseID, LegalStatus_2.
        LegalStatusTypeID, LegalStatus_2.LegalStatusDate
    HAVING (LegalStatus_2.LegalStatusTypeID = 62)
    ) AS qrySub
LEFT JOIN LegalStatus
    ON qrySub.NextLegalStatusID = LegalStatus.LegalStatusID
WHERE (
        qrySub.LegalStatusDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-01-01 00:00:00'
                    , 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-07-01 00:00:00', 102)
        ) OR (
        LegalStatus.LegalStatusDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                    '2013-01-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                    '2013-01-07 00:00:00', 102)
        ) OR (qrySub.LegalStatusDate < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-01-01 00:00:00', 102)
        ) AND (
        LegalStatus.LegalStatusDate > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-01-07 00:00:00', 
            102)
        )
```

You need to join the records for `LegalStatusTypeID` = 62 to the next record for any given case, then use the ID of that next case to get the date which is the end of applicability of the `LegalStatusTypeID` = 62.

Since you are talking about cases which had a `LegalStatusTypeID` = 62 *during* your date range, you need cases where the start date is in your date range, or the end date is in your date range (or both), or your date range is between the case's `LegalStatusTypeID` = 62 start and end dates.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply.  What I am needing is a query for finding all the caseID that have currently or have had legalStatusTypeID = 62 as the current status during a particular date range.  The current date may precede the start date and there may be a  record with a date between or after the end date of my date range.
For instance in my original example data record #2 would be the current legalstatusID for date range 1/1/13 to 7/1/13 even though the date for that record is 10/1/12.  This record is the current legalStatusID until the record with date 10/1/13 is added.

Comment: I've pretty much rewritten my answer, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT *

  FROM   LegalStatus
  WHERE  LegalStatusTypeID = 62 AND
         LegalStatusDate BETWEEN '01/01/13' and '07/01/13'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm understanding your question as seeking to list all CaseID values where the legal status for the case remains at 62 for the entire period that starts on '20130101' and goes up to but not including '20130701'. The legal status of a case on a given date is determined by the most recent LegalStatusTypeID value for that case before or on the given date.

If that's what you want, I think this might do it.

```
declare @fromD smalldatetime = '20130101';
declare @uptoD smalldatetime = '20130701';
with Cases as (
  select distinct CaseID
  from LegalStatus
)
  select CaseID
  from Cases
  where (
    select top (1) LegalStatusTypeID
    from LegalStatus as L
    where L.CaseID = Cases.CaseID
    and LegalStatusDate <= @fromD
    order by LegalStatusDate desc
  ) = 62 and not exists (
    select *
    from LegalStatus as L
    where L.CaseID = Cases.CaseID
    and LegalStatusDate > @fromD
    and LegalStatusDate <= @uptoD
    and LegalStatusTypeID <> 62
  )
```

This selects CaseID values for which the status on '20130101' is 62 and for which there is no subsequent status change to a value different from 62 after '20130101' but before '20130701'. If that's not what you want, perhaps this will still help. This query assumes that the legal status of a case can only change once per day, i.e., that (CaseID,LegalStatusDate) is a candidate key for your table.

I didn't test it very much, since you provided so little sample data to explain what you wanted.

Update: The original poster has clarified the question in a comment below. The following query should identify those CaseID values where the legal status for the case was 62 at any point (even just for one day) during the specified period. It selects those cases where the status was 62 on '20130101' together with those cases where the status became 62 at any point within the period.

```
with Cases as (
  select distinct CaseID
  from LegalStatus
)
  select CaseID
  from Cases
  where (
    select top (1) LegalStatusTypeID
    from LegalStatus as L
    where L.CaseID = Cases.CaseID
    and LegalStatusDate <= @fromD
    order by LegalStatusDate desc
  ) = 62 or exists (
    select *
    from LegalStatus as L
    where L.CaseID = Cases.CaseID
    and LegalStatusDate > @fromD
    and LegalStatusDate < @uptoD
    and LegalStatusTypeID = 62
  )
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.  You are close but not quite correct.  I am looking for a legalstatusID that is current for anytime during the date range, not necessarily for the whole date range. Even if the legalStatusID is current for one day during the date range.

Comment: Since the version of TSQL was not specified, it may not support CTEs.

Comment: T-SQL has supported CTEs since SQL Server 2005. Extended support for SQL Server 2000 ended earlier this year, so it should be fair at this point to give answers that are valid for all versions less than 10 years old and for every still-supported version.